# Указатель на форму верхнего уровня, что это?

Tags: .net, c++

Добрый день.

Давно возник вопрос что есть указатель на форму верхнего уровня и ли как его там... В windows forms обозначается "`^`"... Это не простой указатель... Пробовал заменить на  "`*`", не работало ничего. В искал в яндексе, воообще ничего не нашел. Так что это? Для чего он нужен? Почему не обойтись "`*`"? Просто использую его как указатель, а что это не понимаю...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Символ **^** (сircumflex) используется в C++/CLI для обозначения ссылок на управляемые объекты (object reference). Символ ***** используется для неуправляемых указателей.

Не знаю, что и как вы искали, но эту информацию можно найти в той же [википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI#Handles).

Comment: А чем управляемые обьекты отличаются от неуправляемых? Можете привести примеры обьектов этих типов?

Comment: System::Object - управляемый, std::vector<T> - неуправляемый. Стоит почитать какие-нибудь книжки или статьи про .NET и C++/CLI, а потом начинать писать. Иначе набьете шишек граблями, которые сами раскладываете.

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь буду знать что читать))))